# Why haven't the 2nd generation Digi-destined (excluding Hikari and Takeru) aged?

Tags: digimon

In the beginning of episode 1 of Digimon Tri, we see glimpses of the second generation Digi-destined (excluding Hikari and Takeru).

From the vague scenes, it appears that they have not aged much, if at all (especially considering that Hikari and Takeru, who are more or less the same age, have aged rather noticeably). Why is this the case?

Answer (score 1):

Great question. I'm not sure, but I can pose a few plausible theories:

- the supposed battle between Alphamon and the four Digimon 02 cast happened a while before the story of Digimon Tri and the original Digidestined all moved on
- the producers don't want to spoil what they look like at an older age, so they used such footage
- it's just a bunch of silhouettes, so we can't be sure if they aged or not

If you've watched the second and third movie, you'd know that the disguised version of Ichijouji Ken by Gennai looks taller and more grown up. Of course, I know that you asked this question before even the second movie was released. But hopefully, the next few movies will answer instead of create more questions.

Comment: If it's a great question you should upvote it. It helps it's visibility.